# Cordova inAppBrowser redirect error: invalid_request

Tags: cordova

I am using angularjs with cordova. I am getting a url from a web api with $http.get("web_url"). Then I open the returned URL in the inAppBrowser, and that should redirect me to another page. I have pasted that returned URL into my browser and it works fine. In the app however, I am getting the following error, and I'm not being redirected `error: invalid_request`. I'm using cordova 3.4.0. This is the applicable code:

```
        var ref = window.open(encodeURI(base_url+provider_url), '_blank',  'location=yes');

        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { console.log('start: ' + event.url); });
        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { console.log('stop: ' + event.url); });
        ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { console.log('error: ' + event.message); });
        ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { console.log(event.type); });
```

Please let me know if you need additional information. Can you see anything wrong?

Comment: what is the url you are trying? Does it include 'http://'?

Comment: @islanddave Hi, solved, just removed `encodeURI`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var ref = window.open(base_url+provider_url, '_blank',  'location=yes');
```